# Is there a way to copy the mesh of a cloth sim at a particular point in time as an individual mesh?

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

Can I take a cloth simulation, animate it and at some point during the simulation pause and copy the mesh in that position as a static mesh? I want to be able to copy the object with its vertices in a certain frame's position and be able to edit that mesh as its own unique object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a copy of the cloth mesh, run the animation, stop it where you want and apply the cloth modifier.

[image]